# Hair particles crossing the ear

Tags: particles, hair

I am setting the hair particles, my so far progress is look like this:

[image]

Problem ares can be seen in above picture, few hair crossing the ear. Where as my comb view look like this:

[image]

My hair setting are as follows:

[image]

Can somebody point out me solution? Thanks in advance.